# Relation between filter order and window length for FIR filter

Tags: filters, filter-design

In case of **FIR filter design**, is the following relation always applicable or there are other relations/formulas also?

If window length is denoted by $M$ ,then filter order will be $M-1$

Comment: [this answer has more relations and formulas](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/42903/typical-filter-orders/42908#42908) but here $N=M-1$ is the filter order, one less than the number of nonzero taps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter order vs number of taps vs number of coefficients](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8685/filter-order-vs-number-of-taps-vs-number-of-coefficients)

Comment: "one less than the number of nonzero taps." I don't think that's correct. The $y[n] = ax[n] + bx[n-50]$ is a 50-order filter, while having just 2 nonzero taps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The number of taps or coefficients in a FIR filter (or window length as you call it) tell the order of the filter. A more general way to see it, to avoid confusions, is to think of the order as the largest delay in the filter. For example, consider the following naive reverb:

$$y[n] = a x[n] + (1 - a) x[n-D]$$

Even though there are only two (visible) coefficients, the order of the filter is $D$ because it’s the largest delay. The window length is $D+1$ but all the middle coefficients are $0$, hence not visible.

Comment: calling a single delay tap (plus an undelayed tap) a *"reverb"* is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: Yeah, you’re right. I hope the “naive” makes it a bit more appropriate.

Comment: Is a zero coefficient a "tap"?